# How to apply syntax highlight in a region?

Tags: vim, plantuml

We have this comment in a HTML file

```
<!--
@startuml
A --> B : DoWork
B --> C : DoWork
@enduml
//-->
```

It's PlantUML code in the comment. How do we have syntax highlight on PlantUML code in HTML comment?

We've installed https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aklt/plantuml-syntax/master/syntax/plantuml.vim and it works fine when there is no `-->` in the way. The `-->` is obviously matched by a pattern in file `/usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/html.vim`.

Our ~/.vim/vimrc has this setting:

```
autocmd FileType xhtml
    \ syntax include @iPlantUML syntax/plantuml.vim |
    \ syntax region rPlantUML start=/^@startuml$/ end=/^@enduml$/ keepend fold contains=@iPlantUML contained containedin=htmlComment
```

My best guess is that when VIM finds `-->`, VIM thinks it is the end of a HTML comment according to the `htmlComment` in file `/usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/html.vim`. How to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax highlighting isn't broken. Your snippet is.

The `-->` ends the HTML comment (see [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/syntax.html#comments)). It also does so in the browser. I pasted your snippet in HTML and XHTML files. The HTML case will show everything after "B : DoWork" while XHTML gives an XML parsing error.

According to the specification, there must not even be a `--` in an HTML comment although most browsers seem to be rather forgiving about this. Turning the arrows around like `<--` still isn't correct HTML but it seems to work (until the time when it will not).

Plantuml also allows short arrows (see [PlantUML Reference Guide Chapter 1.1](https://deepu.js.org/svg-seq-diagram/Reference_Guide.pdf)) which will not interfere with (X)HTML comments. This will not yield arrows with dotted but with solid lines, however.

```html
<!--
@startuml
A -> B : DoWork
B -> C : DoWork
@enduml
//-->
```

It will work in Vim, plantuml and the browser.

Unless there's an undocumented feature in plantuml, you'll have to go without dotted arrows.

**Edit:** @Fuhrmanator came up with the truly creative (and even documented!) workaround of specifying the arrow color and thus breaking up the `--` sequence. Many thanks!

PlantUML uses `#A80036` (or `#darkred`) as default for all arrow colors (see PlantUML Reference Guide Chapter 12.3). Unless somebody decides to change the default colors, it's possible to get the same diagram as in the question by writing the following:

```html
<!--
@startuml
' Redundant color spec to break up double minus not permitted by HTML
A -[#A80036]-> B : DoWork
B -[#A80036]-> C : DoWork
@enduml
//-->
```

Comment: I use `tidy` to check HTML. It didn't print any errors or warnings. Probably the command-line options I use makes `tidy` tolerant. Anyway, thanks for testing and information. I'm now using `B <-- A` instead of `A --> B` as a workaround.

Comment: Edited again to mention the `--` problem. Well, `tidy` was right: what you had first was a syntactically correct HTML comment from `<!--` to the very first `-->` it encountered :-)

Comment: Another (harsh?) workaround if you don't want the double-dash but want the dashed arrow: `A -[#black]-> B : DoWork` which defines a (probably already) black dashed line.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator great idea! I was hoping to find something like this when I wrote my answer but missed it. I edited to include your workaround. Thank you very much.